# Page table bits in linux virtual address (4-level paging)

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging, arm64

what are pgd, pmd pte and page shift bits in a 64-bit virtual address on armV8 CPU with 4-level paging?

I need this information to debug a issue at hand.

Comment: If you're debugging the kernel, surely you have [the kernel source to hand](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-hwdef.h)?

Comment: Yes @Notlikethat. I have it. I tried to look by myself. But the definitions are not straight forward. As these variables are dependant on various other variables and then shifting them to left or right, It is not straight forward to come to a conclusion. Hence the question if someone has an answer already.

Comment: @Notlikethat arm64/memory.txt defines it clearly. I got it now. Posted the same below. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document in here explains very clearly
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm64/memory.txt

Translation table lookup with 4KB pages:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|63    56|55    48|47    40|39    32|31    24|23    16|15     8|7      0|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
 |                 |         |         |         |         |
 |                 |         |         |         |         v
 |                 |         |         |         |   [11:0]  in-page offset
 |                 |         |         |         +-> [20:12] L3 index
 |                 |         |         +-----------> [29:21] L2 index
 |                 |         +---------------------> [38:30] L1 index
 |                 +-------------------------------> [47:39] L0 index
 +-------------------------------------------------> [63] TTBR0/1
```

L0 - PGD, L1 - PUD, L2 - PMD, L3 - PTE

Aarch64 uses only 0-39 bits(3-level paging). Hence For aarch systems, `PGD(L0) = PUD(L1) = [38:30]`. Rest of the mapping remains the same.